# Decode multiple base64 strings from standard input

Tags: bash, macos

I have a file that contains multiple base64 encoded strings split by a new line character:

```
Y2F0Cg==
ZG9nCg==
ZmlzaAo=
```

When I execute: `cat b64s.txt | base64 -D` I expect to see:

```
cat
dog
fish
```

but I only see:

```
cat
```

What's an easy way to execute `base64 -D` for each line read from standard in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while read line; do base64 -D <<< "$line"; done < b64s.txt
```

For what it's worth, on my Linux system with GNU coreutils 8.28 the decode flag is `-d` and it automatically decodes a file with multiple strings:

```
$ base64 -d b64s.txt
cat
dog
fish
```

Comment: What does this look like if `b64s.txt` is piped via cat in the example above?

Comment: `cat b64s.txt | while ...`. The redirection with `<` avoids the [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 1):

The stock `/usr/bin/base64` in macOS will only decode the first string from your input file. But base64 decoders vary wildly, there's been a fair amount of discussion on the topic even her in SO.

Python is installed by default in macOS, and the Python 2.7 interpreter that probably lives at `/usr/bin/python` will likely behave the way you want.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin ghoti.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Tue Jan 30 11:45:51 PST 2018; root:xnu-3248.73.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ cat i
Y2F0Cg==
ZG9nCg==
ZmlzaAo=
$ python -m base64 -d < i
cat
dog
fish
```